# Lua table not accessible (attempt to index a nil value)

Tags: lua

I have a table that looks like this:

```
{
  block_0 = {
    hash = "98d1a61c4e3d6394b2970a2a5c44ec2caf172ad5c6844b114867b31fa528220e",
    index = 0
  }
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to access the `index` and `hash` values of `block_0` by saying `chain["block_0"]["hash"]`? It is not working. When I use this line, I get the error `attempt to index a nil value (field 'block_0')`. How can I properly access `hash` and `index`?

EDIT: Here is some more context:

```
function add_thing()
  block_name = "block_0"
  block = { }
  block[block_name] = { }
  block[block_name]["hash"] = ""
  block[block_name]["index"] = ""
  block[block_name]["hash"] = "this is a test hash"
  block[block_name]["index"] = 10
  return block
end

chain = { }
table.insert(chain, add_thing())
require 'pl.pretty'.dump(chain)
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? How is this blob being used by your code?

Comment: Done. @CurtisF.

Comment: `chain[1]["block_0"]["hash"]` or did you perhaps mean `local chain = add_thing()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting the return value of `add_thing` into `chain`.  Thus chain is now a table of tables.  To index the correct field you have to index `chain` first, i.e. `chain[1]["block_0"]["hash"]`.  I rather suspect that this is not the intended behaviour and you want to do the following

```
local function add_thing(chain)
  local block_name = "block_0"
  chain[block_name] = {
    hash = "this is a test hash",
    index = 10
  }
end

local chain = {}
add_thing(chain)
print(chain["block_0"]["hash"]) -- this is a test hash
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oYjwPpTfgTyEvUHD)

This works as expected because tables are reference types.

Comment: Do I need to use the `local`

Comment: @MattX You don't have to but it's recommended to keep variables local to where they are used.